# Combo boxes where available choices are unique and dependent on the choice in previous combo box

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set in another file that has 3 columns with thousands of rows. All 3 columns have values that are not unique.

I need 3 combo boxes.

The first combo box is for selecting from column "A" (bringing back unique values) for the different types of business units.

Next, depending on the business unit, combo box 2 is for selecting a specific customer (depending on the business unit selected).

Finally, combo box 3 is for selecting from the different cost centers that exist for a given customer.

I need unique values for all 3 columns.

I think I have combo box 1 with the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim wbExternal As Workbook   '<-- the other workbook with the data
Dim wsExternal As Worksheet  '<-- the worksheet in the other workbook
Dim lngLastRow As Long       '<-- the last row on the worksheet
Dim rngExternal As Range     '<-- range of data for the RowSource
Dim myCollection As collection, cell As Range
On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wbExternal = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\sarabiam\desktop\OneFinance_Forecast_Model\FY19_New_Forecast_Model_Data_Tables.xlsm", True, True)
Set wsExternal = wbExternal.Worksheets("#2Table_Revenue") '<-- identifies worksheet
Set rngExternal = wsExternal.Range("A8:A" & CStr(lngLastRow))
Set myCollection = New collection

With ComboBox1
    .Clear

    For Each cell In Range("A8:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        If Len(cell) <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            myCollection.Add cell.Value, cell.Value
            If Err.Number = 0 Then .AddItem cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell

End With
ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0

wbExternal.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True  '<-- updates the worksheet on your screen 
any time there is a change within the worksheet

End Sub
```

Comment: This can be anything. If we don't see the rest of the code it's very unlikely that we can answer that. Please [edit] your question and show all the relevant part of the code. Reading [mcve] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: It is the developer comments, replacing what is in the dictionary dic, for key Dn.Value to an array arr.

Comment: I would expect `(arr)` to just blow up with an error at run-time, if `arr` is an array. These parentheses are forcing VBA to evaluate the variable as an expression, ...which makes no sense for an array. Isn't that blowing up with a *type mismatch* error?

Comment: Who wrote the comment you're asking us to interpret, and did they write anything else?

Comment: I have a data set in another file that has 3 col with thousands of rows. In all 3 columns I have values that are not unique. I need 3 combo-boxes. In the 1st combo box, I need to be able to choose what is in column "A" (bringing back unique values) for the diff. types of business units I have. Next, depending on the bus. unit, I need combo box 2 to allow you to select a specific customer (depending on the business unit you have selected). Finally, in combo box 3, I need the user to be able to select the different cost centers that exist for a given customer. I need unique values for all 3 col.

Comment: `lngLastRow` has a value of zero when you use it...   And what is the actual question here?  Your title no longer matches the rest of your post.

Comment: Sorry Tim. I am very new to these forums. I need three combo boxes with the explanation I gave above. I think I am good with the first combo box but would appreciate any help or suggestions for combo box 2 and three? Could you please help me?

Comment: Is the data for the other lists located in Columns B and C?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Please, use indentations in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty generic approach - it only loads the data once, into an array, then uses that to reset list content on selection of a "previous" list.

```
Option Explicit

Const dataPath As String = "C:\Users\usernameHere\Desktop\tmp.xlsx"
Dim theData 'source data

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    LoadData
    Me.cboList1.List = GetList(1, "")
End Sub

Private Sub cboList1_Change()
    Me.cboList2.Clear
    Me.cboList2.List = GetList(2, Me.cboList1.Value)
    Me.cboList3.Clear
End Sub

Private Sub cboList2_Change()
    Me.cboList3.Clear
    Me.cboList3.List = GetList(3, Me.cboList2.Value)
End Sub

'Return unique values from source data, given a specific column
'  If given a value for "restrictTo", filter on match in column to "left"
'  of the requested value column
Function GetList(colNum As Long, restrictTo)
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, rv()
    Dim dict As Object, v, ub As Long, inc As Boolean

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ub = UBound(theData, 1)
    ReDim rv(1 To ub) 'will set final size after filling...
    n = 0

    For i = 1 To ub

        v = theData(i, colNum)
        'are we restricting the values we collect based on a different list?
        If colNum > 1 And Len(restrictTo) > 0 Then
            'is this value valid?
            inc = (theData(i, colNum - 1) = restrictTo)
        Else
            inc = True 'collect all values
        End If

        If inc And Not dict.exists(v) Then
            'don't already have this value - add to array and dict
            n = n + 1
            dict.Add v, True
            rv(n) = v
        End If

    Next i
    ReDim Preserve rv(1 To n) 'resize array to size of content
    GetList = rv
End Function

'load data from external file
Private Sub LoadData()
    With Workbooks.Open(dataPath).Worksheets("#2Table_Revenue")
        theData = .Range(.Range("A8"), _
                         .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)).Value
        .Parent.Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a "compile error" method or data member not found

Comment: Well, it's quite probable you need to make some changes, such as editing the names of the combobox controls to match those on your form.  Is that where you're getting an error?

Comment: what do you mean by edit the names of the combobox controls? Name the ranges on the data set table?

Comment: The list controls on your form have names - in my code sample I used `cboList1`, `cboList2` and `cboList3` - it looks like you might be using `ComboBox1` and ? So you need to make the necessary adjustments.